# YouTube Data API v3: ChannelSections.list gives strange results for some channels

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

This is a duplicate of [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6552), still unanswered.

The problem is that for some channels (e.g. YouTube Movies or TV) the `ChannelSections` are invalid.

To reproduce the issue: Call `ChannelSections.list` on  (with snippet and contentDetails) for channel IDs UCl8dMTqDrJQ0c8y23UBu4kQ or UCczhp4wznQWonO7Pb8HQ2MQ. These are valid channel IDs for the [Movies](http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCczhp4wznQWonO7Pb8HQ2MQ) and [TV](http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCl8dMTqDrJQ0c8y23UBu4kQ) channels .

Check out the API results [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channelSections.list?part=snippet%252CcontentDetails&channelId=UCl8dMTqDrJQ0c8y23UBu4kQ&_h=21&) and [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channelSections.list?part=snippet%252CcontentDetails&channelId=UCczhp4wznQWonO7Pb8HQ2MQ&_h=23&).

The results should be of a defined type. They should also provide contentDetails (as requested) to allow me to present interesting things from the channel. However, results yield strange results of type "`channelsectionTypeUndefined`", and no contentDetails sections providing playlists/channels.

**Notes:**
When browsing through the YouTube website and clicking through to e.g. the "popular on youtube" channel, you actually stay on a URL that links to that channel. However, for "TV Shows" and "Movies", it takes you to, e.g. https://www.youtube.com/user/YouTubeShowsUS. Should these channels be handled in a different manner than asking for the ChannelSections?

Comment: Since the `channel_id`s provided in your question are from channels generated by YouTube, I wouldn't rely on the results from the API. Also, checking the source code of the channel_id "`UCczhp4wznQWonO7Pb8HQ2MQ`". The results (using the API) are = *channel not found*.  Now its channel_id was changed to `UClgRkhTL3_hImCAmdLfDE4g`. Maybe it is related to region restrictions... If you still looking an answer, can clarify: what do you need retrieve from these channels, exaclty?